# Can't fix "Behat only can run if test mode is enabled" in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle, behat

After I run

```
php admin/tool/behat/cli/util.php --enable
```

I see this message:

```
Acceptance tests environment enabled on http://127.0.0.1, to run the test use: 
vendor/bin/behat --config /var/www/education/moodle/admin/tool/behat/cli/tests/behat/behat/behat.yml
```

Then I run my behat feature file:

```
vendor/bin/behat --config /var/www/education/moodle/admin/tool/behat/cli/tests/behat/behat/behat.yml local/intelliboard/tests/behat/student_dashboard.feature
```

Its message to me:

```
Behat only can run if test mode is enabled. More info in http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Acceptance_testing#Running_tests
```

I read that doc a lot, there is no any info to solve my issue, because I did util.php --enable and even check a behat.yml and found my student_dashboard.feature test and context variable and related for it .php filename with test steps.

I even install NodeJS Gherkin validator and check my feature for errors - its clean.

Comment: Hi, you finally did solved? Can you explain what you did? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Yes I did, but then had another trouble)
Any way to solve it you can read this links (they were pretty helpful for me):

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-40392
https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-37046

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-43450

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have those two configuration entries, `behat_dataroot_parent` must be added to your configuration file and set to the same value as `behat_root`

```
$CFG->behat_dataroot_parent = '/var/www/bht_moodledata/';
$CFG->behat_dataroot = '/var/www/bht_moodledata';
```